# Manipulating a list to increase code efficiency, struggling

Tags: python, vpython

```
from visual import *

planet = ['merc','venus','earth','mars','jupiter','saturn','uranus','neptune']
planetv = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
planetp = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
```

Essentially, I want to create new variables that are as follows:

```
merc.m = 2
venus.m = 3
earth.m = 4
```

...

```
merc.p = 10
venus.p = 20
earth.p = 30
```

...

Without changing the `planet` list, as I will need to access 'merc', 'venus', etc. later in the code.

Comment: What does this have to do with "increasing code efficiency"?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. Are there already objects in the main namespace called `merc`, `venus`, `earth`, etc.? Or are you asking how to create them, such that you can give them `m` and `p` attributes?

Comment: It increases code efficiency because it means I don't have to set the attributes one by one, but instead just access their values in a list.

Comment: Minor nit regarding inconsistent abbreviation.  All the planets are spelled out except mercury.

Comment: Yes, it was just easier to type.  Can someone elaborate on where I can read more on the topic that Ferdinand Beyer suggested?  I'm new to python, so I don't really know what's going on in his code...

Comment: Bob, you should read up on python classes: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html The tutorial is a little opaque, I like the explanation in 'A Byte of Python': http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Python_en:Object_Oriented_Programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to create global variables with the names given by the list `planet`, with each variable bound to an object that has attributes `m` and `p`, set to the values in the lists `planetv` and `planetp`, respectively.

If this is correct, here is a way to do it:

```
# Create a class to represent the planets.  Each planet will be an
# instance of this class, with attributes 'm' and 'p'.
class Planet(object):
    def __init__(self, m, p):
        self.m = m
        self.p = p

# Iterate over the three lists "in parallel" using zip().
for name, m, p in zip(planet, planetv, planetp):
    # Create a Planet and store it as a module-global variable,
    # using the name from the 'planet' list.
    globals()[name] = Planet(m, p)
```

Now you can do:

```
>>> merc
<__main__.Planet instance at 0x...>
>>> merc.m
2
>>> merc.p
10
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do (based on your description).  Can you give me a resource that I can look at to better understand this topic?  I'm having trouble following what you're doing, as my python skills are not as proficient.

Comment: @BobJohn: Maybe you should start with the Python tutorial?  I will add some more comments to my code, but this really is basic stuff.

Comment: What is this topic specifically?

Comment: @Bob In the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) you'll find [this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) part about classes and also an introduction to [dicts](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). The [docs](http://docs.python.org/) includes this information: [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip), [globals](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals).

Answer (score 2):

Well, the planets are just strings, so you can't set attributes on them. Furthermore, creating lots of global variables dynamically as Ferdinand suggests is very *very* rarely a good idea, it's better to use a `dict`.

Building on Ferdinands answer, I suggest including the name of the planet as an attribute (I think you'll find that you will need it). Now you can have these `Planet` objects in a `dict` or a `list` (to preserve the order), whatever suits your needs at the time, and all the relevant information is readily at hand in either case.

```
planet = ['merc','venus','earth','mars','jupiter','saturn','uranus','neptune']
planetv = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
planetp = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]

class Planet(object):
    def __init__(self, name, m, p):
        self.name = name
        self.m = m
        self.p = p

planets = [Planet(name, m, p) for name, m, p in zip(planet, planetv, planetp)]
planet_dict = dict((p.name, p) for p in planets)

for p in planets:
    print "{0}: {1} {2}".format(p.name, p.m, p.p)
print "Mass of earth: {0}".format(planet_dict["earth"].m)
```

**EDIT:** Forget my previous suggestion, I've changed my mind.

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple, I'd use a dictionary to create the mapping.

Like this -

```
planet = ['merc','venus','earth','mars','jupiter','saturn','uranus','neptune']
planetv=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
planetp=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]

planet_map = {}

for i, p in enumerate(planet):
    planet_map[p] = {'m': planetv[i],
                     'p': planetp[i],
                    }

print planet_map
```

Now you can access `planet_map['merc']['m']` and `planet_map['merc']['p']`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of doing this with dictionaries?

```
planetv_dic = {'merc':2, 'venus': 3,'earth':4,'mars': 5,'jupiter': 6,'saturn': 7,'uranus': 8,'neptune': 9}

planetp_dic = {'merc':10, 'venus': 20,'earth':30,'mars': 40,'jupiter': 50,'saturn': 60,'uranus': 70,'neptune': 80}
```

or given that you already have a your lists, build your dictionaries using for-loops:

```
 planetv_dic = {}
 planetp_dic = {}
 for i in xrange(len(planet)):
    planetv_dic[planet[i]] = planetv[i]
    planetp_dic[planet[i]] = planetp[i]
```

you can then access your list of planets by using something like

```
 planetv_dic.keys()
```